# If $f(x)>x$ then it can't be $K$-Lipschitz with $0<K<1$.

Tags: real-analysis

> We say that $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz if $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|,$$
>   for all $x,y$. Let $f=[0,\infty )\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a function such that $f(x)>x$ for all $x$. Then $f$ can't be $K$-Lipschitz for $K\in (0,1)$. Is it true or false ?

I was thinking thinking about $f(x)=x+a$ with $a>0$ but unfortunately it doesn't work. Then of function s.t. $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)- x=0$, but s.t. will be s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$. So I suppose that it's true, but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>0$ then
$$1<\frac{f(x)}{x}\leq \frac{|f(0)|+|f(x)-f(0)|}{x}\leq\frac{|f(0)|+K|x-0|}{x}$$
and by taking the limit for $x\to+\infty$, we get 
$$1\leq \lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{|f(0)|+K|x-0|}{x}=K.$$

Comment: hey, very elegant :-) (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose it's true, i.e. there is $K\in (0,1)$ s.t. $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|,$$
for all $x,y\geq 0$. Since $f(x)>x$, we have $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=+\infty ,$$ and thus, there is $M>0$ s.t. $f(x)\geq f(0)$ when $x\geq M$. Moreover, there is $N\geq M$ such that $f(0)\leq (1-K)x$ whenever $x\geq N$. Finally, if $x\geq N$,
$$x<f(x)\leq K x+f(0)\leq Kx+(1-K)x=x,$$
that is a contradiction. So it's true.